# How To Implement Correct Sorting Algorithm in Priority Queue?

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

I need your help with implementing the correct sorting algorithm for Priority Queue. Apparently I've done this wrong as it creates a duplicate node. I'm stumped on this, any help would be greatly appreciated. I need to get this right as I will use this on both increase() and decrease() methods.

Check my sort() method below in the code.

Here is my code:

```
public class PriorityQueueIntegers implements PriorityQueueInterface {

    // number of elements
    private int numberOfElements;

    // element
    private int element;

    // priority
    private int priority;

    // Node
    Node head = null, tail = null;

    // returns true if the queue is empty (no items in queue)
    // false if queue is (has at least one or more items in queue)
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return ( numberOfElements == 0 );
    }

    // returns the value of the item currently at front of queue
    public int peek_frontValue()
    {
        return head.getValue();  // return the value in the head node
    }

    // returns the priority of the item currently at front of queue
    public int peek_frontPriority()
    {
        return head.getPriority();
    }

    // clear the queue
    public void clear()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        numberOfElements = 0;
    }

    // insert the item with element and priority
    public void insert(int newElement, int newPriority)
    {
        // if head node is null, make head and tail node contain the first node
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(newElement, newPriority);
            tail=head; // when first item is enqueued, head and tail are the same
        }
        else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(newElement, newPriority);
            tail.setNext(newNode);
            tail=newNode;            
        }
        sort(newElement, newPriority);

        numberOfElements++;
    }

    public void increase(int findElement, int priority_delta)
    {
        Node current = head;

        if (numberOfElements > 0)
        {
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.getValue() == findElement)
                {
                    int newPriority = current.getPriority() + priority_delta;
                    current.setIncreasePriority(newPriority);
                }
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        } else throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty Queue - increase failed");
    }

    public void decrease(int findElement, int priority_delta)
    {
        Node current = head;

        if (numberOfElements > 0)
        {
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.getValue() == findElement)
                {
                    int newPriority = current.getPriority() - priority_delta;
                    if (newPriority < 0)
                    {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't be a negative number");
                    }
                    current.setDecreasePriority(newPriority);
                }
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        } else throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty Queue - increase failed");
    }

    private void sort(int value, int priority)
    {
        Node current = head;
        int v = value;
        int p = priority;

        Node temp = new Node(v, p);

        if (numberOfElements > 0)
        {
            while (current != null && current.getNext().getPriority() < p)
            {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            temp._next = current._next;
            current._next = temp;
        }
    }

    public int remove_maximum()
    {
        int headDataValue = 0;
        if ( numberOfElements > 0 )
        {
            headDataValue = head.getValue();
            Node oldHead=head;
            head=head.getNext();
            oldHead.setNext(null);                     
            this.numberOfElements--;
        }
        else throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty Queue - dequeue failed");
        return headDataValue;  // returns the data value from the popped head, null if queue empty
    }

    public String display()
    {
        Node current = head;
        String result = "";

        if ( current == null )
        {
            result = "[Empty Queue]";
        }
        else
        {
            while ( current != null )
            {
                result = result + "[" + current.getValue() + "," + current.getPriority() + "] ";
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Inner Node Class
    private class Node
    {
        private int value;
        private int priority;
        private Node _next;

        public Node (int element, int priority_delta)
        {
            this.value = element;
            this.priority = priority_delta;
            _next = null;
        }

        protected Node(int element, int priority_delta, Node nextNode)
        {
            this.value = element;
            this.priority = priority_delta;
            _next = nextNode;
        }

        public Node getNext()
        {
            return _next;
        }

        public int getValue()
        {
            return this.value;
        }

        public int getPriority()
        {
            return this.priority;
        }

        public void setIncreasePriority(int newPriority)
        {
            this.priority = newPriority;
        }

        public void setDecreasePriority(int newPriority)
        {
            this.priority = newPriority;
        }

        public void setNext(Node newNextNode)
        {
            _next = newNextNode;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: adding a concrete example might help in getting responses quicker

Comment: When I try to output the nodes, there is a duplicate node of the one I inserted into the priority queue.

Comment: Why are you not using `java.util.PriorityQueue<Integer>` ?

Comment: My teacher required us to create a custom made priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that your code currently creates duplicate nodes. Your `insert` method creates a node:

```
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(newElement, newPriority);
        tail=head; // when first item is enqueued, head and tail are the same
    } else {
        Node newNode = new Node(newElement, newPriority);
        tail.setNext(newNode);
        tail=newNode;            
    }
```

This method then calls `sort` that also creates a node:

```
    Node temp = new Node(v, p);
    if (numberOfElements > 0) {
        while (current != null && current.getNext().getPriority() < p) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        temp._next = current._next;
        current._next = temp;
    }
```

It does not make a lot of sense to me that a `sort` method would create a new node. You should either insert the node in the right position in `insert` or the `sort` method should move it to the correct position. If you take the first approach then you'll need to change you `increase` and `decrease` methods.

A potential method to move a node to the correct position, in pseduocode, would be:

```
move node:
    walk through queue and find both
        node that's next points to the one you are moving (from)
        last node that has higher priority than the one you are moving (to)
    set from.next to node.next
    set node.next to to.next
    set to.next to node
```

Comment: sprinter, thanks. How do I use the sort method to move the node to correct position?

Comment: I'll add some pseudocode to my answer - presume if this is a homework assignment you aren't looking for the solution.

Comment: That is fine with me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still stumped on this. Tell me if I'm on the right track below.

Comment: if (numberOfElements > 0)
        {
            while (start != null)
            {
                if (start.getNext().getValue() == v && start.getNext().getPriority() == p)
                {
                    target = start.getNext();
                }
                else if (start.getNext().getPriority() > p)
                {
                    temp = start.getNext();
                }
                start = start.getNext();
            }

Comment: That code doesn't seem to relate to the pseudo code I added. You need to find where the node's previous is and where to insert and then move it.

Comment: I'm still at a loss. I just don't get it.

Comment: Can anyone else help me out?

Comment: @Picard90 what exactly are you asking for help on? Implementing the 'move' function? If you're finding that difficult then perhaps take the approach of inserting in the right place rather than moving afterwards. Your 'increase' and 'decrease' methods could just remove the node and reinsert with new priority.

Comment: I abandoned the sort method, and implemented new code that inserts the new element in right order at the beginning. I'm going to work on increase and decrease methods. I almost gets it....cross my fingers!